# Displaying an object atributes in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x

The pycharm doesn t displaying the prints

PyCharm doesn't display the atribute values of my class

[image]

Comment: Don't add an image of your code. Write it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing: `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Suppose your code is in `test.py` file:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.a = attr

p = P(4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(p.a)
```

Run it using `python test.py` or via PyCharm and you will see 4 in output.

**Reason**:

When you execute your Python script, Python interpreter sets the variable `__name__` to `'__main__'`, the condition `__name__ == '__main__'` evaluates to `True` and `print` function is executed.

When you `import test.py` as a module in another module, the interpreter sets `__name__` to `test` and the `print` function call won't be executed.

Refer to [What does if **name** == “**main**”: do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more details.